# Connect to Excel with ADO - don't know Sheet Names

Tags: vba, excel

I'm connecting to Excel with ADO, but it only works if I specify the sheet names.  I won't know those at runtime.  Is there any method to get the sheet names?  Excel automation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you've open the ADO connection, you need call the OpenSchema() method which returns a results set with the sheet names as "table_name"

I'm a bit rusty with VBA but that should look something like that

```
Dim oConn
DIm oRs
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim sConn
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=somepathtoXLS; xxx not sure some other connection str props..."
oConn.Open sConn

Set oRS = oConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
Do While Not oRS.EOF 
   sSheetName = oRS.Fields("table_name").Value
   '// do something with the sSheetName
   oRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: If there are listobjects in your Excel file they will be included in the adSchemaTables list. Anyone know how to differentiate between listobjects and sheets?

Comment: I can't get JET to work so used `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` with additional properties: `;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""`

Answer (score 0):

Via automation:

(1) set a reference to the appropriate Excel library - I'm using Excel 2003 so it's "Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library"

(2) create an Excel `Application` object

(3) open the relevant `Workbook`

(4) iterate through the `Worksheets` collection

(5) get the `Name` property of each `Worksheet`

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\foo.xls")

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    MsgBox ws.Name
Next ws

wb.Close
xlApp.Quit
```