# Rename Workbook with name of first worksheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to rename each workbook in a folder as the name of the first worksheet in the workbook.  For example, if the Workbook is called "71107" and the worksheet in that workbook is called "foobar", I would like the workbook to be renamed "foobar".

My current progress is as follows:

```
Sub RunMe()
Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim objWkbk As Workbook
Dim objFile As File
Dim folderpath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

folderpath = "D:\test\"

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(folderpath).Files
    oldpath = objFile.path
    Set objWkbk = Workbooks.Open(oldpath)
    newpath = path & "NEWNAME\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xls"
    objWkbk.SaveAs Filename:=newpath
    objWkbk.Close
Next objFile
End Sub
```

This code runs extremely slowly (in the order of 10 seconds per file).  My files are not large, only around 40kb each.  Is there a faster way to perform this operation?  I also don't need to save a new copy of each file, I'm quite happy to just rename the file I just don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: This is really as it gets already, other than running a hidden instance of Excel in the background which would be a little quicker. The only other way would be to use ADO to return the name of the first sheet of the closed book

Answer (score -1):

There are two things, which takes so long one is Open and SaveAs. 
The Open can be avoided with ADO as mentioned and more details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397158/connect-to-excel-with-ado-dont-know-sheet-names)

Then you can also not use SaveAs because it is not opened but you can just rename the file using something like:

```
Name GivenLocation & OldFileName As GivenLocation & NewFileName
```